# how to use ejs local variable in angular 2

Tags: angular, sails.js, ejs

How can I use `<%= my_var %>` (ejs template engine in sails.js) in angular 2, for example in this context:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<span><%= my_var %></span>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'title';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_var` will only be replaced with a value when your angular code is inside a script tag inside your ejs template. Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // your code
</script>
```

However when the angular code is inside its own js file it will not work because the js file will be loaded on the client side, after the server has processed the ejs file.

A possible solution would be to have some angular code, that creates a service holding your data (processed on server), in the ejs template like shown above. In your component you can inject this service and use the variables.